# How to copy Cyberduck bookmarks to another MacBook?

Tags: macos, backup, restore, cyberduck

Got a new MacBook, how can I copy Cyberduck bookmarks from my old MacBook?

Comment: Please consider un-accepting the outdated answer in exchange for the current one by dakishimesan

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Update 2018-07-23

The below is outdated. See the [answer by @dakishimesan](https://superuser.com/a/1218092/302157).

### Original Content

May be worth just copying the entire Cyberduck folder across. It's located at `~/Library/Application Support/Cyberduck`. There is a `Favorites.plist` file in there if you *just* want the bookmarks. Put that in the same location on your new MacBook.

Comment: May be worth it to migrate the whole user profile to the new machine :-) I would probably go insane without all my applications, preferences, files, etc.

Comment: `~/Library/Preferences/ch.sudo.cyberduck.plist` might also be a good idea to migrate.

Comment: This is no longer accurate. See @dakishimesan's answer, https://superuser.com/questions/203941/how-to-copy-cyberduck-bookmarks-to-another-macbook/1218092#1218092.

Answer (score 26):

Full answer from [the Cyberduck documentation](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/faq#Preferencesandapplicationsupportfileslocation):

> **Preferences and application support files location**
>
> Preferences are saved in
>   *~/Library/Preferences/ch.sudo.cyberduck.plist*.
>
> **Bookmarks**, history, ​profiles and workspace information is saved in the application support directory. These settings are shared with
>   ​Cyberduck CLI and ​Mountain Duck.
>
> *~/Library/Group Containers/G69SCX94XU.duck/Library/Application Support/duck/*
>
> Navigate to the Library folder using *⌘⇧-L* or use *Go → Go to
>   Folder…* in Finder.

Comment: Any idea, how to prevent the loss of the sort order? Is that in the profile files?

Answer (score 18):

You can drag and drop the bookmarks from the list (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) to a Finder window or the desktop, then copy or move those files to your new machine.

These files don't contain your stored password, this is still in your keychain. Enter it anew on the new machine, or migrate your `login` (default) keychain you can find in `/Users/yourname/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`.

If your machine is brand new, you could consider using Migration Assistant to migrate all your data to the new machine.

Answer (score 10):

In Sierra:

User -> Library -> Group Containers -> G69SCX94XU.duck -> Library -> Application Support -> duck

Comment: This is where I found the bookmark files for Mountain Duck as well :)

Answer (score 5):

For backup, just simple: access bookmarks pages, at here select bookmarks which you want to backup (or press CMD A to select all bookmarks), then drag-n-drop them to Desktop or anywhere

For restore: drag-n-drop backup file (.duck) to Cyberduck!

Comment: This works well, but doesn't persist saved passwords :/

Comment: In this case (for scp, sftp), I think you need to config same me: add a key to all session remote